# nginx redirection to subdomain thats a proxy to another domain

Tags: nginx

I use nginx to act as a proxy between 2 servers. I have a domain aswell as a subdomain attached to an ip. I need to send requests to a third ip via a subdomain for convoluted reasons that I wont bore you with. 
An issue im having is communication between servers with rest. Any actions I take in my webapp result in

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Ive been trying to figure it out and I got one login request to pass but after that everything stopped working.
The domain I have setup and everything works fine the subdomain looks like this

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        server_name api.example.com www.api.example.com;

        location / {
        proxy_pass          "http://x.x.x.x:8080$request_uri";
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade          $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection       "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Client-Verify  SUCCESS;
        proxy_set_header    X-Client-DN      $ssl_client_s_dn;
        proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Subject    $ssl_client_s_dn;
        proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Issuer     $ssl_client_i_dn;
        proxy_read_timeout 1800;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
    }

}
```

Im relative new to nginx but to me I think this should work as a proxy. Ive had it call one request but fail there after could it either be a firewall/network issue?

Comment: That error smells like a TLS cert issue, as in you might be missing a domain on your cert - I see you're using both the naked api. and www.api. and this could be what is tripping you up. Try making requests to the domain that is on the cert.

Comment: Went through it in the end you were right @Chase the www. was colliding and causing an issue. But it also was that Cors were not enabled and because I was sending over content like video Nginx buffer request was timing out. Thanks for the info